# The best way to load page data into div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two divs at my page, one left div and one right div.

In my left div, I have an table with rows of data that comes from my database. Im using ng-repeat to loop:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="box in boxar">
  <td>{{box.type}}</td>
  <td>{{box.mac}}</td>
  <td>{{box.serial}}</td>
  <td><a href="box.id">Remove</a> | <a href="box.id">-> customer</a> | <a href="box.id">History</a></td>
 </tr>
```

As you can see, I have links that belongs to the rows. When I click on one of the links, I want to load a page/template Into the right div, with the data that belongs to the box that I choosed (box.id).

Can anyone give me an example how to this In angular?

In PHP, I would do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['box_id']))
{
  $query = "SELECT * FROM boxes WHERE box_id=$_GET['box_id']";
  //Print out the data from the selected box
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want.

HTML:

```
....
<a ng-click='getId(box.id)'>Remove</a>
....
<div class="right-div">
   <ng-include src="template"></ng-include>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getId = function(id){
  $scope.id = id; //Here you get your ID
  $scope.template = id; //Here you load the template, provided its a proper path
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the built-in `ngInclude` directive.

Please look at the following [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ImqWj65YllaCYD5kX5E?p=preview)

***EDIT***

So in your right div you can add the `ngInlcude` tag. Then you need to match up your box.id to a `ng-template` id

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="page1">
    <h1 style="color: blue;">This is the page 1 content</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: But how do I load the data that belongs to box.id In the template?

Comment: @Bryan. Instead of `href`, use `ng-click` and pass the `box.id` and assign it to the `src` of `ngInclude`.

Comment: @Zee: And how do then get the Id from the src-tag? Can you post a answer with an example of how you would do It?

Answer (score 0):

you can try jquery `load` function.

more details look at this [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: This is not angular way of doing things.

Comment: okey. sorry for my answer. In my application, use `load` function but it's not `angularjs`. so i have no idea that this `load` function is not using in `angularjs`.